# how to display the current logged on users picture from a relationship laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to retrieve the user's photo and display it in a thumbnail form which i have stored in public/assets/uploads/thumbnail/. I tried auth()->user()->user_detail->file_name but I can't get it to work. How do you do it ?

Comment: Can you share the dd(auth()->user()->user_detail)?

Answer (score 0):

you have to first define a relationship if they are stored in different table 
like i did in model

```
public function imagedata() {
    return $this->hasMany(Images::class, 'listID', 'id');
}
```

and after that when you get the user just call this method like this

```
    $listingimg = Listings::findOrfail($id);
```

and for calling the relationship

```
foreach (listingimg  as $singleIlisting) {
            $singleIlisting->imagedata;
        }
```

modify the code according your needs as if needed and by the way relatio is one to many

Comment: Yeah my internet's just back now

Comment: No, I just want to display it in the dashboard. After the user has successfully logged on.

Comment: can you share where did you define the relation an how you defined it ?

Comment: I want to share with you? How can id o it?

Comment: take a screen shot or just share it in comment :) if this make sense

Comment: Ah ok, That's why i can't access it. I have this model UserDetail that contains the user_id foreign key. I want to access the file_name in the user_details table. How can i do something like ? UserDetail::findOrfail($id);

Comment: the user_id is a foreign key to the user_details table

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e33382   thats the modal and this is controller http://prntscr.com/e333nn take a look at them (y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134588/discussion-between-faisal-mehmood-awan-and-a-sand).

Comment: do i have to use foreach once again??